# Mysql alias giving unknown column

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(IF(`VAT`<1,(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`, 0))+SUM(DISTINCT `VATValue`),2)
FROM 
    `salesinvoice`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products` 
    ON `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id` = `salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
```

The problem is that the query gave me an incorrect result, because `VAT` was being duplicated, because this is a one to many (Bear in mind this isn't the question).
So I tried this

```
ROUND(SUM(IF(SUM(DISTINCT `VAT`)<1,(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`, 0))+SUM(DISTINCT `VATValue`),2)
```

Which also didn't work. Apparently you can't use DISTINCT in a sum this way.
So this is where I tried to use an alias, but I get unknown column when I try this. So here is my final code, which is the question I am asking.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DISTINCT `VAT`) as v,
    ROUND(SUM(IF(v<1,(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`, 0))+SUM(DISTINCT `VATValue`),2)
FROM 
    `salesinvoice`
    LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products` 
        ON `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id` = `salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
```

As you can see I put `SUM(DISTINCT VAT)` as v in a separate column and was hoping to use the result in the calculated column, but it isn't working, and I have no idea why.

Viki888 suggested using a subquery, and so I have now tried this, but I am still getting the unknown column error. Perhaps I am doing it wrong. Here is the updated code

```
SELECT
   (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT `vat`) FROM `salesinvoice`)as v,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(v<1,(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`, 0))+SUM(DISTINCT `VATValue`),2)
FROM `salesinvoice`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products`
   ON `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id` = `salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
```

Right I think I am close to a solution. This doesn't give me an error, but doesn't give me the results I want. I have to replace the number 3 with the id of the line, but I am not sure how to pass the id to the subquery

```
SELECT
   ROUND(SUM(IF(v<1,(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`, 0))+SUM(DISTINCT `VATValue`),2) FROM `salesinvoice`
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT `vat` as v FROM `salesinvoice` WHERE `SalesInvoice_id`=3)as j
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products`
   ON `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id` = `salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
```

I finally found out that the best way is to do an inline SELECT, but the problem is this. I am still getting a figure which is higher than what I should be getting. So something is being duplicated somewhere. I am starting to think that my VAT might not be the problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ROUND(SUM(IF((SELECT DISTINCT si2.`VAT` FROM `salesinvoice` as si2 WHERE si2.`SalesInvoice_id`=si.`SalesInvoice_id`)<1,(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`, 0))+SUM(DISTINCT `VATValue`),2) as total
    FROM `salesinvoice` as si
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products` as sip
   ON si.`SalesInvoice_id` = sip.`SalesInvoice_id`
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data along with expected result?

Comment: Try nested query. First take **SUM OF DISTINCT** in **inner query**, then in **outer query**, you can access the value **v**.

Comment: You cannot use the result of an aggregate column as part of the same query (other than in an HAVING clause). @viki888 suggestion is a way to go.

Comment: Please edit your query to include table alias's to give us a clue where the fields are coming from.

Comment: Hi viki888. I have added a subquery, but still getting the unknown column. Have I done it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question because I have finally come up with the solution to the problem, but not the answer to the question. This is that I didn't need the alias at all, and I solved it another way. So this nullifies my question. However I will give my answer anyway.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ROUND(SUM(IF(`VAT`<1, (`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`, 0)),2) as total
    FROM `salesinvoice` as si
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products` as sip
   ON si.`SalesInvoice_id` = sip.`SalesInvoice_id`
```

The big thing was to put DISTINCT after SELECT, which solved me having to have an alias. The other thing I did was to remove the part where I added the VATValue, as if there was no VAT I didn't need to add that value. I feel so stupid that it took me a whole day to work this out. However adding that value shouldn't have changed the answer if it was zero, so I don't understand that, but finally I got it to work. Can't believe I have lost so much time over something which was quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the query as following, alias will not work for conditions.

```
SELECT 
SUM(DISTINCT `VAT`) as v,
ROUND(SUM(IF(SUM(DISTINCT `VAT`) < 1,(`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`, 0))+SUM(DISTINCT `VATValue`),2)
FROM 
`salesinvoice`
LEFT JOIN `salesinvoice_products` 
    ON `salesinvoice`.`SalesInvoice_id` = `salesinvoice_products`.`SalesInvoice_id`
```

Comment: If you look at my second bit of code you will see that I have already tried this and I get this error #1111 - Invalid use of group function. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need to separate out the joins, grouping and aggregating salesinvoice_products before joining to salesinvoice and then sum the results over the result making a decision what it is you want to use in the sum.
Something like this perhaps.

```
select  sum(case when vatvalue = 0 then nonvatvalue else vatvalue end) as TotalInvoice
from
( 
(select si.id,
         case when si.vat < 1 then 0 else si.vatvalue end as vatvalue 
FROM  `salesinvoice` si
) si
join (select sip.id, sumsum((`Unit_Cost`*`Quantity`)*`ExchangeRate`) nonvatvalue
        from salesinvoice_products` sip group by sip.ip) sip 
ON si.id = sip.id
) t
```